# PHP Warning: SQLite3Stmt::execute(): Unable to execute statement: database is locked

Tags: sqlite, symfony

My questions in related to my another one:

[Poor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599863/poor-performance)

In apache logs I have errors like this:

PHP Warning:  SQLite3Stmt::execute(): Unable to execute statement: database is locked in /home/marek/devel/sf2/cities/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/SqliteProfilerStorage.php

I am using MySQL so why I am getting error about SQLite3?

Could someone help resolve this error?

**[EDIT]**

The only way of disabling profiler is:

```
public function __construct(ProfilerStorageInterface $storage, LoggerInterface $logger = null)
{
    $this->storage = $storage;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->collectors = array();
    **$this->enabled = false;**
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony2 stores debug and profiling data in SQLite database (in {root}/app/cache/dev/profiler.db file) and seems like in dev mode you send a lot of requests and it locks SQLite database. If you want to test performance of your application - do not use DEV environment

Comment: If you can find {root}/app/cache/PROD/profiler.db then you turned on debug & profiling for PROD mode. Look at your configuration for prod and be sure you use {root}/web/app.php instead of app_dev.php

Comment: try to remove profiler:false at all and check config_prod.yml